# How to programmatically turn on and off bluetooth, wifi and sound on OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

How can I turn on and off the wifi and bluetooth connections, change the sound and brightness levels on OSX?

Comment: That's four questions in one...

Comment: CAN wifi and bluetooth connections be turned on programmatically?? I'd imagine that that would be a serious security risk...

Comment: @ShmuelA.Kam: I think they can, because you don't have to press any hard-buttons on the computer in order to turn them on/off, this is done trough software layer. Security is another question, UNIX knows how to manage permissions.

Comment: Sorry about that. I had misread the title, and saw iOS instead of OSX. Yes, the security issues on a PC would be MUCH less than on a mobile device, with it's many Apps of unknown trust-levels.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply execute the right commands :-) You could probably even use AppleScript.

- Wifi: `ifconfig en1 off` or `networksetup -setairportpower off`
- Bluetooth: You'll probably need http://www.frederikseiffert.de/blueutil/
- Brightness: I found this c utility for you: http://mattdanger.net/2008/12/adjust-mac-os-x-display-brightness-from-the-terminal/

It's probably all possible without `exec()` calls, but it's easier this way.

Comment: Or even `NSTask` since we'd all like to use ObjC only instead of mixing up languages ;)

Comment: wifi: `sudo ifconfig en0 down`,  `sudo ifconfig en0 up`