# Turn on and off the Bluetooth connection on Mac

Tags: macos, xcode6

I am new to mac . I want to ask how can i programmatically just turn on and off the Bluetooth connection on Mac?Can anyone suggest any simple tutorial ,any link.I searched but dint get the result.
Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically turn on and off bluetooth, wifi and sound on OSX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328183/how-to-programmatically-turn-on-and-off-bluetooth-wifi-and-sound-on-osx)

Answer (score 7):

[blueutil](http://www.frederikseiffert.de/blueutil/) is an open-source command-line [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) utility to control Bluetooth I/O in OSX.

```
$ blueutil status # Print bluetooth status
$ blueutil on # Switch bluetooth on
$ blueutil off # Switch bluetooth off
```

---

> Using the Core Bluetooth framework, there are three ways you can
>   reconnect to a peripheral. You can:
>
> - Retrieve a list of known peripherals—peripherals that you’ve discovered or connected to in the past—using the retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers: method. If the peripheral you’re looking for is in the list, try to connect to it.
> - Retrieve a list of peripheral devices that are currently connected to the system using the retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices: method. If the peripheral you’re looking for is in the list, connect it locally to your app.
> - Scan for and discover a peripheral using the scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options: method. If you find it, connect to it.

- [Best Practices for Interacting with a Remote Peripheral Device](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/BestPracticesForInteractingWithARemotePeripheralDevice/BestPracticesForInteractingWithARemotePeripheralDevice.html)
- [Bluetooth Device Access Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/devicedrivers/conceptual/bluetooth/Bluetooth.pdf)

Comment: Can you please tell the step by step procedure for the same?

Comment: the commands are now :
blueutil -p 1 # on, blueutil -p 0 #off and blueutil # only for status. also blueutil --help

Answer (score -3):

I experienced this too, but was able to resolve it much easier.

1. Open "Bluetooth File Exchange"
2. Go to Preferences
3. If 'Send file' or 'Browse' is selected, select 'None'

This should either automatically turn off bluethooth, or at least free up the system lock/block on the UI controls.